# Не работает массив из объектов класса

Tags: c#, классы

Создал класс, пытаюсь создать массив таких объектов и записать в соответствующие поля свои записи. Но при записи вылезает ошибка: "System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта." Ниже привел код написанный в цске класса и строки на которых выдает ошибку.
Класс:

```
class Question
{
    public string Text = null;
    public string TrueAnswer = null;
    public string FalseAnswer1 = null;
    public string FalseAnswer2 = null;
    public string FalseAnswer3 = null;


    public Question()
    {
        Text = null;
        TrueAnswer = null;
        FalseAnswer1 = null;
        FalseAnswer2 = null;
        FalseAnswer3 = null;
    }

    public Question(string text, string trueAnswer, string falseAnswer1, string falseAnswer2, string falseAnswer3)
    {
        Text = text;
        TrueAnswer = trueAnswer;
        FalseAnswer1 = falseAnswer1;
        FalseAnswer2 = falseAnswer2;
        FalseAnswer3 = falseAnswer3;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Вопрос: " + Text + " Правильный ответ: " + TrueAnswer;
    }




    Question[] mas = new Question[101];
    mas[1].Text = "123"; - строка с ошибкой
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Question[] mas = new Question[101];
for(int i = 0; i < mas.Length; i++)
  mas[i] = new Question();
mas[1].Text = "123"; // строка без ошибки
```